# get image size properties with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, images

What am i trying to do:

I'm setting up a responsive e-mail template in Marketing Cloud using images from a datafeed.
The image url's are successfully retrieved from the datafeed with AMPscript.
However, the images have various dimensions. (horizontal vs vertical images)
I want to get the image properties (height and width) to display the images correct in the e-mail.
Don't know if this is even possible.

I am new to SSJS and tried the following:

```
<script runat=server language="JavaScript">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");
    var img_url = Variable.GetValue("@image");
    
    function getMeta(img_url){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            var img_width = this.width
            var img_height = this.height
            Variable.SetValue("@image_w", img_width);
            Variable.SetValue("@image_h", img_height);
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The capabilities of that function rely on **[Document() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/Document)** which is only available client-side as it interacts with the DOM.

That on top of the **[onload function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)** also being limited to clientside as nothing is loaded until after all of the SSJS and AMPsript is completed.

What you could do is create a middle page to grab all this information and use ajax to send it to another code resource to collect and store inside of a DE. You then can do a lookup to that DE when you want to find width/height or whatever other attributes you want to attach to it.

Something like

Middle Page: (Script tags are Inline Concat otherwise Content Builder would strip them)

```js
%%=CONCAT('<s','crip','t src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></s','cript','>')=%%

%%=CONCAT("<s","crip","t>")=%%
  var attr = [];
  var img_url = "myexampleImgURL"; //set this to be dynamic entry and/or can make array and loop through it to pass multiple records for insert

function getMeta(url){   
    attrObj = {}
    img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    attrObj.ImgUrl = url;
    attrObj.ImgWidth = img.width;
    attrObj.ImgHeight = img.height;
    attr.push(attrObj);
}

getMeta(img_url);

var str = JSON.stringify(attr);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST","https://myExamplePageUrl.com")
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xhttp.send(str)

xhttp.onload = function() {
  console.log('response:', this.responseText)
}

%%=CONCAT("</s","crip","t>")=%%
```

Upsert Page:

```js
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  
  var jsonpost = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
  var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonpost);
  //Write('json: ' + Stringify(json));

var myDE = DataExtension.Init("Image_Attributes");
var resp = myDE.Rows.Add(json)
Write(resp);
  
</script>
```

Data Extension:

```
Name      |  Data Type  |  Length  |  Primary Key  |  Nullable  |  Default Value 
ImgUrl    |    Text     |   4000   |      N        |     N      | 
ImgWidth  |    Number   |          |      N        |     N      | 
ImgHeight |    Number   |          |      N        |     N      | 
ImgDate   |    Date     |          |      N        |     N      |  Current Date
```

I would recommend putting a data retention policy on this as it will continue adding more and more of the same. To make sure to get the latest versions, what you can do is do an ordered lookup to get the info.

Something like:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @url = "myexampleImgURL"
SET @ImgRS = LookupOrderedRows("Image_Attributes",1, "ImgDate Desc", "ImgUrl", @url)
SET @ImgRow = Row(@ImgRS,1)
SET @ImgWidth = Field(@ImgRow,"ImgWidth")
SET @ImgHeight = Field(@ImgRow,"ImgHeight") 
]%%
```

This would all have to be a pre-process and not inside the email sort of real time thing. It is far from clean or performant, but the best alternative I could come up with off top of my head.

Comment: Yeah I figured that's the case, but was hoping for a different answer. Thanks for the explanation. I'll just have to figure out a workaround.

Comment: @tommy83 if I have answered your question, please mark my answer as accepted so that others that have your issue will be able to easily find this solution as well.